# Unexpected behaviour with JQuery mousedown and mouseup events

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, mouseevent

I am working on a small web application on which users get a tooltip with options after selecting a piece of text from a div (contenteditable = true).

If the user select a text, the tooltip `fadesIn`  on "mouseup" event. The event `mousedown` is used to `fadeOut` the tooltip.

Everything works like charm as far as the user doesn't select the whole text. If (s)he does so, and then clicks somewhere else on the div, the tooltip fades out and in again.

An example of this behaviour can be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/7NEk3/275/
The events are coded as follows:

```
            $('#show-bubb-text').mouseup(function(e) {
                var selection = getSelected();
                if (selection && (selection = new String(selection).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''))) 
                {
                    selectionImage.attr('href', 
                    url.replace('{term}', encodeURI(selection))).css({
                        top: e.pageY - 30, //offsets
                        left: e.pageX - 13 //offsets
                    }).fadeIn();
                }
            });

            $(document.body).mousedown(function() {
                selectionImage.fadeOut();
            });
```

1. Select for example "CREATE A LOGO", and you'll see that a tooltip fades in, if you click somewhere else in the div, the tooltip will fade out.
2. Select now the whole chunk of text, i.e. from 'SMS' to '/'. The tooltip will appear as expected, but if you click on either the selection or on the non-selected part, the tooltip will fade out and back in.

Is this an expected behaviour? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** This seems to work well on Firefox. However, it does not on Chrome or Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is occurring when you click within the active selection. You can recreate this by making any selection and click inside the active selection. The reason for this is due to the order in which the events are called. The active selection isn't cleared before you call your 'getSelection' function. Therefore, your application is detecting an active selection even though the selection is cleared immediately after you 'mouseup'.

One solution could be clear the selection on 'mousedown'. Something like:

```
function clearSelection() {
    if ( document.selection ) {
        document.selection.empty();
    } else if ( window.getSelection ) {
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
}
```

Then in your 'mousedown' function:

```
$(document.body).mousedown(function() {
     clearSelection();
     selectionImage.fadeOut();
});
```